# ScrollView content positioning

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `scrollView` that contains a `collectionView` and an `imageView`.

`Bounce on scroll` is disabled.

When my app starts, I get this screen:

[image: start screen]

But when I scroll up I get this:

[image: scroll up] (Note the whitespace between the imageView and the top of the screen)

I want to prevent the whitespace from appearing at the top of the screen when I scroll.

Comment: please share your code to other users can test what you are doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your scrollView's content inset is being adjusted automatically because of the safe area at the top of the screen. In this case it would be happening so that content does not end up behind the notch.

You can disable this by setting the scrollView's content inset adjustment behaviour to "Never" either in IB (in the "Size Inspector"):

[image]

Or code (Swift would be something similar):

```
self.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever;
```